# How to increase memory due to RAM on Ubuntu 18.04 without BIOS

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, ram

I want to increase memory due to RAM on Ubuntu 18.04 without BIOS
Without BIOS, since I can’t enter the Advanced BIOS in any way
As far as I know, although I don’t have a discrete video card, but integrated graphics, I can increase it as I know.
Even though I do not play demanding games, but 8 mb is very small...
And the integrated graphics already work on video memory at the expense of RAM.

How to do it on Ubuntu 18.04, LXDE Desktop?

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to reduce the amount of RAM that gets dedicated for integrated video *without* using the UEFI/BIOS? 

Comment: The only way to alter this is at the firmware level.  This happens *before* the system boots.  If you don't have BIOS or firmware access you are not going to be able to make the changes necessary to allocate it differently as the memory allocation is done at the firmware/hardware level